# K-means distance parameters in Matlab - Varying results

Tags: matlab, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a matrix I am working with which 300x5000 and I wanted to test which distance calculation parameter is the most effective. I got the following results:

'Sqeuclidean' = 17 iterations, total sum of distances = 25175.4

'Correlation' = 9 iterations, total sum of distances = 32.7

'Cityblock' = 34 iterations, total sum of distances = 105175.3

'Cosine' = 11 iterations, total sum of distances = 11.9

I am having trouble understanding why the results vary so much and how to choose the most effective distance parameter. Any advice?

EDIT:

I have 300 features with 5000 instances of each feature. 
the function looks like this:

[idx, ctrs, sumd, d] = kmeans(matrix, 25, 'distance', 'cityblock', 'replicate', 20)

with interchanging the distance parameter. The features were already normalized.

Thanks!

Comment: You should state clearly which function you are using, which of 300 and 5000 is the dimension of your problem and which is the number of samples, and how you are using this function.

Comment: to understand why you get different results using different methods you really should try to understand what the different methods are actually doing.  Then pick the method that best lines up with your problem rather than the method that gives you the "best" result

Comment: Your edit doesn't address the underlying problem.  You haven't defined what a good cluster is.  The metrics you give (iterations to convergence, total sum of distances) are not meaningful measures of a good cluster.  Different distance functions will, of course, have different total sums, and will take different iterations to converge.  What is your actual goal in clustering?

Answer (score 0):

As slayton commented, you really need to define what 'best' means for your particular problem.

The only thing that matters is how well the distance function clusters the data.  In general, clustering is highly-dependent on the distance function.  The two metrics that you've selected (number of iterations, sum of distances) are pretty irrelevant to how well the clustering works.

You need to know what you're trying to achieve with clustering, and you need some metric for how well you've achieved that goal.  If there's an objective metric to determine how good your clusters are, then use that.  Often, the metric is fuzzier: does this look right when I visualize the data.  Look at your data, and look at how each distance function clusters the data.  Select the distance function that seems to generate the best clusters.  Do this for several subsets of your data, to make sure that your intuition is correct.  You should also try to understand the result that each distance function gives you.

Lastly, some problems lend themselves to a particular distance function.  If your problem has spatial features, then a Euclidean (geometric) distance is often a natural choice.  Other distance functions will perform better for different problems.

Comment: my goal is to identify features that are highly correlated and those that aren't in order to be left with features that have low correlation among themselves

Comment: I'm not sure that k-means clustering will help you do what you want here.  I sounds like you really want something to reduce the dimensionality of your features to those that provide a better description of the space.  There are a lot of classification-type approaches to this, but I would see how far you can get just looking at the covariance matrix.  I'll edit my answer to give a little more detail.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I'm not sure that I can really help you with this topic.  You might consider techniques like [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to help reduce the dimensionality of your feature set.  You might also try a quick-and-dirty multivariate regression (see `regress`) where the dependent variable is the index of the instance.  This should give you a rough idea of which features are valuable and which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Distance values from different

- distance functions
- data sets
- normalizations

are **generally not comparable**. Simple example from reality: measure distances in "meter" or in "inch", and you get very different results. The result in meters will not be better just because it is **measured on a different scale**. So you **must not compare the variances of different results**.

Notice that k-means is meant to be used with *euclidean* distance only, and may not converge with other distance functions. IMHO, L_p norms should be fine, and on TF-IDF maybe also cosine. But I do not know a proof for that.

Oh, and k-means works really bad with high-dimensional data. It is meant for low dimensionality.

Comment: Thanks, What would you suggest for high-dimensional data? (within Matlab)

Comment: I don't use Matlab. You probably should try to find a working distance function first. Then you can use most distance-based outlier detection methods.